# Как в preference-headers вставить SwitchPreference

Tags: android

В AndroidStudio 1.4 есть шаблон настроек SettingsActivity при формировании он создает 4 xml файла с разметкой меню настроек. Один из них это pref_headers.xml с таким вот содержимым:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- These settings headers are only used on tablets. -->

<header
    android:fragment="******.myapplication.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />

<header
    android:fragment="*****.myapplication.SettingsActivity$NotificationPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_notifications" />

<header
    android:fragment="*****.myapplication.SettingsActivity$DataSyncPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_data_sync" />
```

Все замечательно только мне нужно добавить туда еще SwitchPreference, который выглядит так:

```
<SwitchPreference
        android:dependency="notifications_new_message"
        android:key="notifications_new_message_vibrate"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_vibrate"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
```

Просьба подсказать, как это сделать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14825690/3212712

Answer (score 1):

SwitchPreference надо вставлять в xml фрагмента. Название "pref_headers" говорит само за себя.